Is Malachi 3:1 foretelling the coming of John the Baptist or Jesus Christ?
The book of Malachi prophesies about the coming of the messenger of the covenant or in some other Bible versions, the angel of the covenant.
Malachi 3:1

Behold, I will send my messenger, and he shall prepare the way before me:
and the Lord, whom ye seek, shall suddenly come to his temple,
even the messenger of the covenant, whom ye delight in:
behold, he shall come, saith the LORD of hosts.
2 But who may abide the day of his coming?
and who shall stand when he appeareth?
for he is like a refiner's fire, and like fullers' soap:
3 And he shall sit as a refiner and purifier of silver:
and he shall purify the sons of Levi, and purge them as gold and silver,
that they may offer unto the LORD an offering in righteousness.

We do know that it was John the Baptist who came to prepare the way for Jesus Christ, but then it goes ahead to say that who shall stand when this messenger appears?
So who exactly is this verse foretelling his coming? Jesus Christ or John, the Baptizer?

Chances are this verse is foretelling the coming of John the Baptist who came as a priest.

This question is similar to: How many distinct persons are present in Malachi 3:1-5? Who are they? Can we link them prophetically to persons from the New Testament?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Good Q., + 1. Malachi is foretelling both the coming of John the Baptist, who is followed on by Jesus Christ. Your Q., really encompasses vv. 1 & 2, which you reference anyway. See my Q:- https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/86258/did-the-imparting-of-the-gospel-of-jesus-christ-start-with-the-ministry-of-jes ... and particularly my comment under Nigel's answer. According to the DSS the pronoun "his" before coming (in v.2), should be "them" and not "his". Note also my exchange with Mike Borden.

@OldeEnglish, Thanks for the kind word, I hope it will exhaustively answer all my questions regarding that prophecy, thanks for the upvote too.

Thank you for your upvote. If by "prophecy", you mean Daniel's "70 Weeks" prophecy, as distinct from Malachi's prophecy, then by all means check out all that I referred to under Dottard's answer to Q: 86258.

Answer
In fact, Malachi foretells the coming of both John the Baptist and Jesus Christ.
Explanation

“Behold, I am sending My (Jehovah’s) messenger (John the Baptist), and
he (John) will clear the way before Me (Jehovah). And the Lord
(Jehovah) whom you are seeking shall suddenly come to His (Jehovah”s)
temple, even the Messenger of the Covenant, in whom you delight.
Behold, He comes, says Jehovah of Hosts” (Mal 3:1).

We need to understand one part of the Scripture through other parts of Scripture. So, let us see.
When John the Baptist was born, “his father Zacharias was filled of the Holy Spirit and prophesied” and said quoting Malachi 3:1:

“And you, child, will be called Prophet of the Most High, for you
will go before the face of the Lord to prepare His ways”.

Jesus Christ Himself identifies John quoting Malachi 3:1:

“This is he about whom it has been written: "Behold, I send My
messenger" before Your face, who "will prepare Your way before You"
(Luke 7:27).

What is interesting to notice here is that Mark quotes again Malachi 3:1 with a similar quote from another famous OT prophet. This second prophecy will clearly point out who the Massesnger of the Covenant is:

“as it has been written in the Prophets, "Behold, I send My messenger
before Your face, who will prepare Your way before You” (this is
Malachi 3:1); “the voice of one crying in the wilderness. Prepare the
way of the Lord, make His paths straight" (_this is Isaiah 40:3) -Mark
1:2-3.

Let us see what exactly Isaiah is prophesying:

“The voice of him (John) who cries in the wilderness: Prepare the
way of Jehovah; make straight in the desert a highway for our
God” (Is 40:3).

The Scripture is crystal clear: John the Baptist was preparing the way of Yahweh, our God!
So Yahweh was to come after John.
And we see Jesus coming after John!
No wonder, John said regarding Jesus:

“He who comes after me is mightier than I, of whom I am not
fit to stoop down to loosen the thong of His sandals” (Mar 1:7).

[John is talking in the superlative of his own cousin!!]

“This One it is who has come after me, who has been before me, of
whom I am not worthy that I should loose the thong of His sandal”
(John 1:27).

“the Lord” in Malachi 3:1
Who is the Lord in Mal 3:1?
The word is “Ha Adon” in the OT Hebrew. It occurs 5 other times in the OT and all the 5 times it refers to Yahweh God:

“and says the Lord (Ha Adon), Jehovah of Hosts, the mighty One of Israel” (Is 1:24).

“For, behold, the Lord (Ha Adon), Jehovah of Hosts” (Is 3:1).

“So the Lord (Ha Adon), Jehovah of Hosts shall send” (Is 10:16).

“Behold, the Lord (Ha Adon), Jehovah of Hosts” (Is 10:33).

“declares the Lord (Ha Adon), Jehovah of Hosts” (Is 19:4).


Next we see Ha Adon in Malachi 3:1:

“And the Lord (Ha Adon) whom you are seeking shall suddenly come to His temple”.

Who is the Ha Adon, the Jews and the children of Israel are seeking?
It is their God Yahweh Himself (2 Chr 11:16).
Whose Temple is the temple in Jerusalem?
It is the Temple of Yahweh Elohim (2 Chr 26:16).
In whom do the children of Israel and Jews delight?
It is in Yahweh their God (Psalms 37:4).
Jesus the Messenger of a Covenant
Yahweh talks about a second and better Covenant He will make with the children of Israel. Quoting Jeremiah 31:31-34, we see in Hebrews:

“For finding fault, He said to them, "Behold, days are coming, says
the Lord, and I will make an end on the house of Israel and on the
house of Judah; a new covenant shall be, not according to the
covenant which I made with their fathers in the day of My taking hold
of their hand to lead them out of the land of Egypt; because they did
not continue in My covenant, and I did not regard them, says the Lord.
Because this is the covenant which I will covenant with the house of
Israel after those days, says the Lord, giving My Laws into their
mind, and I will write them on their hearts, and I will be their God,
and they shall be My people" (Heb 8:8-10).

Jesus established this new and better Covenant with the children of Israel:

“And He said to them, This is My blood, that of the New Covenant,
which is poured out concerning many” (Mark 14:24).


“And because of this He is Mediator (Messenger) of a new covenant”
(Heb 9:15).


“Jesus the Mediator (Messenger) of a new covenant” (Heb 12:24).

Conclusion
So, the first messenger who belonged to Yahweh to prepare His way before Him was obviously John the Baptizer, the voice crying out in the wilderness. But the second Messenger of the Covenant is the Lord (Ha Adon) whom Israel seeks, in whom Israel delights and whose is the Temple in Jerusalem. He made a new Covenant with Israel.

“But who can endure the day of His coming? And who will
stand when He appears?” (Mal 3:2)


“For the day of Jehovah is very great and terrifying, and who can
endure it?” (Joel 2:11).

This is Jesus Christ the Lord.
He is the One to come and He is the One to appear.

Your right that Jesus is the messenger of the new covenant, was he also the angel of the presence who went before the Levites carrying the ark of the old Covenant?

Can you give me the reference for the angel of the presence who went before the Levites?

The angel who went before the ark .

The reference your looking for is at Isaiah 63:9. "In all their affliction He was afflicted, And the angel of His presence saved them; In His love and in His mercy He redeemed them; And He lifted them and carried them all the days of old." Some examples of them being lifted all the days of old can be found at Exodus 13;21, Exodus 14:19, Exodus 14;24. Also read Exodus 17:5-6 where the Lord is talking and cross reference that with 1 Corinthians 10:4.

Thank you, Mr. Bond for the references. I agree with you. @SoFewAgainstSoMany – See Mr. Bond’s comment. Angel of Yahweh, Angel of God, Angel of presence are all the same. There is only one difference here. Jesus is not an angel in “nature”, that is, He doesn’t belong to angel “kind” like Seraph or Cherub. He belongs to God “kind”. The Hebrew word for angel is “malak” which means messenger or representative. Jesus is the Messenger, Representative, Spokesman, “the Word” who belonged to the “God” kind (John 1:1).

"Ha Adon" is indeed the Hebrew translation of "the Lord", whether it be that we are referencing Jehovah (meaning He who causes to become), or Jesus (meaning Jehovah's salvation). Such is the fallacy of composition - the error of assuming that what is true of a member of a group is true for the group as a whole - when the NT, supposedly non-biased, translators chose to replace our divinity's truly important and decidedly distinctive names with, and unabashedly, a mere "title", the same for both even. Such be the folly of "Trinitarian" bias. The "Messenger of the Covenant" is Jesus.

The short answer is that Malachi 3:1 is referring to both John the Baptist and Jesus Christ. John the Baptist is verified at Mark 1:1-4. Jesus Christ is verified as the messenger of the covenant at Isaiah 40:3. This is also verified at John 1:23, "He said, I am a voice of one crying in the wilderness, "Make straight the way of the Lord, as Isaiah the prophet said."
Then you have Jesus speaking at Matthew 11:7-10 acknowledging John the Baptist. Notice vs10, "This is the one about whom it is writt3en, "Behold, I send My messenger before your face, who will prepare your way before you."
It is also clear here that the coming of the Lord equals the coming of Messiah/Jesus Christ. The understanding is also mirrored in the shift from "before me" to "before thee."

How is it possible for the verse to refer to two different entities, it seems as if the subject of the verse is a single entity when it is read in whole.

Because the context of Malachi 3:1 dictates there are two entities in view. Obviously the first is John the Baptist. The second is the Lord Jesus Christ. Notice the words in the verse, "AND THE LORD whom you seek will suddenly come to His temple." The definition of the word "And" (which is a conjunction) is used to introduce an additional comment or interjection. Moreover, look at Malachi 3:2, "But who can endure the day of His coming? And who can stand when He appears? For He is like a refiner's fire and like fullers soap." Read the rest of the verses, this is "NOT" John the Baptist.

Malachi 3:1 is a dual-fulfillment prophecy. Many biblical prophecies have dual-fulfillments, where the prophecy is kinda-met, but not fully, sometimes called a "shadow fulfillment" or a "near/short-term fulfillment", until the full fulfillment later comes.
In Malachi 3:1's case, the shadow fulfillment was Jesus' first coming. The full fulfillment is Jesus' second coming.
On the surface, Malachi 3:1 mentions two individuals, and one or two groups of people: the messenger coming before the Lord, the Lord coming Himself, those who can stand before the Lord, and the sons of Levi who get purged like silver and gold.
(I think the latter two groups of people are the same group, but am not certain)
`Behold, I will send my messenger, and he shall prepare the way before me`

The first person is one who comes as a messenger, preparing the way before God.
The Jews were expecting this to be Elijah, but Jesus seems to say it's John the Baptist.
So let's go back a moment, why were the Jews expecting Elijah? Because God told them He'll send Elijah, specifically, in Malachi 4:5-6:

“Behold, I am going to send you Elijah the prophet before the coming
of the great and terrible day of the Lord. He will turn the hearts
of the fathers back to their children and the hearts of the children
to their fathers, so that I will not come and strike the land with
complete destruction.”

If God says "Elijah", He probably means "Elijah".
But Jesus tells his disciples something odd, in Matt 17:10:

"And His disciples asked Him, “Why then do the scribes say that Elijah
must come first?” And He answered and said, “Elijah is coming and
will restore all things; but I say to you that Elijah already came,
and they did not recognize him, but did to him whatever they
wanted. So also the Son of Man is going to suffer at their hands.”
Then the disciples understood that He had spoken to them about John
the Baptist."

This is weird. Jesus is saying (my words, paraphrasing Jesus, using my flawed understanding), "Yes, they are correct, Elijah is coming [future tense]. And when he comes, he will [future tense] restore all things. But also, Elijah has already came" [and the Elijah who already came, the disciples comprehended and scripture confirms was John the Baptist].
So, there is two fulfillments of the Malachi 3:1 passage: Before Jesus' first coming, John the Baptist is the shadow-fulfillment playing the role of Elijah, the Malachi 3:1 role, to prepare the way for Christ's [first] coming.
But God said He'd send Elijah, and Jesus confirms Elijah is still yet to come, and will "restore all things", When? Malchi 4:5 says, before the coming of the Great and Terrible Day of the Lord. i.e. Christ's second coming.
There are many Old Testament prophecies of the Day of the Lord, and they weren't fulfilled at Christ's first coming.
Indeed, the apostles frequently wrote - after Christ's first coming - as if it's still yet to come. Take the whole of 2nd Peter chapter 3 as a good example.
Peter is talking of a future event, and his future event sounds like it meshes well with Malachi 3:2-3:

"But who may abide the day of his coming? and who shall stand when he appeareth? for he is like a refiner's fire, and like fullers' soap: 3 And he shall sit as a refiner and purifier of silver: and he shall purify the sons of Levi, and purge them as gold and silver [...]

I don't feel like this has been fulfilled. I also don't feel like John the Baptist fulfilled "restore all things".
Now, Elijah did show up during Jesus' first coming, along with Moses, on the Mount of Transfiguration, but only three people aside from Jesus saw him, and he didn't turn the hearts of the children to the fathers or restore all things, so that can't have been the fulfillment either.
So when then is Elijah supposed to appear?
We see he's supposed to appear before the coming of The Lord, before the coming of the Great and Terrible Day of the Lord (a day the Bible describes in fairly destructive language).
And when we turn to Revelation 11, we see that God will send, in the end-times, two witnesses, who prophecy and who do signs and wonders, and the signs and wonders listed are thus:

breathing deadly fire
commanding the sky to shut up the rain
turning water to blood
striking the land with plagues

The first two are famously what Elijah did in the Old Testament. The last two are what Moses did in Egypt. Both Elijah and Moses appeared with Jesus on the mount of transfiguration.
The Revelation 11 passage that describes the two witnesses, says the two witnesses, "are the two olive trees and the two lampstands that stand before the Lord of the earth." (Rev 11:4)
This is a direct reference to Zech 4, wherein Zechariah has a vision, and talks with an angel about the vision, and the angel tells him in Zech 4:14: "These are the two anointed ones, who stand beside the Lord of the whole earth."
So if I may lay it out like this:

Zechariah sees two olive trees and lampstands that are two anointed people who stand before the Lord of the earth.
Revelation says the Two Witnesses are those two people, and will witness before Christ's 2nd coming in Jerusalem (to the ""sons of Levi"", perchance? Religious/Orthodox Jews who are loyal to the OT, maybe?).
Revelation says those two witnesses will do miracles that are suspiciously similar to what Moses and Elijah did.
Moses and Elijah appeared with Christ transformed on the mountain.
Malachi says (and Christ confirms) God will send Elijah before the coming of the Lord to prepare His way.

So what is the preparing of His way?
I think John the Baptist (1st coming) and Elijah (2nd coming) minister to people's hearts and call them to repentance, making them more likely to turn to Christ when Christ appears. I'm not exactly sure how Elijah "restores all things" when he appears and stays for 3 1/2 years or so before Christ's second coming. Perhaps he restores them to proper doctrine, to prep them for the arrive of Christ as fulfillment of that doctrine? I am not sure.


3 ...he shall purify the sons of Levi, and purge them as gold and
silver, that they may offer unto the LORD an offering in
righteousness.

According to Luke, John the Baptist, as a priest, was descended from Levi through Aaron. (Luke 1:5) Jesus, on the other was thought to be descended from David through his adopted father Joseph. (Lk. 2:23-38)  Assuming that the text is correct about these facts, and also that Jesus was correct in affirming that John was Elijah, it is clear that Malachi must be talking about John and not Jesus.
Mal. 4:3's reference to John is further supported if John, as some think, was associated with the Essenes (Dead Sea Scrolls sect), for this group was particularly concerned with the purification of the priesthood. Indeed, they actually expected two messiahs, one royal the other priestly. And the priestly messiah, being internal and spiritual, was more important than the royal one, who would be external and political.
Conclusion: The OP's suggestion that Malachi refers to the coming of Jesus Christ cannot be sustained. However, it is possible that Malachi's prophecy refers to John as a messiah - the priestly messiah - and that John might have fulfilled this role if he had lived. Because John was killed, however, he was unable to fulfill the prophecy that he would purify the sons of Levi.
